# How to open desired figure by dialogue box in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Is there any possible way to open the desired figures from a lot of plotted figures in MATLAB?

If it is possible with dialogue box then it will be perfect.

I have like 75 figures plotted after my code but I have closed the figures at end of loops as they are too much.

Is it possible to open just one figure by just entering values necessary for plotting figure in MATLAB at end of program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From [Wikibooks: MATLAB Programming/Handle Graphics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Handle_Graphics#Figure_handles) (emphasis mine):
>
> **Every time you close a figure**, either by using the close function OR by hitting the 'X', **you can no longer access the data**, and
>   attempts to do so will result in an error. Closing a figure also
>   destroys all the handles to the axes and annotations that depended on
>   it.

This means that once you close your 75 figures, they are gone for good.

I would suggest saving all your figures to `.fig` file format, because this will allow you to open them later in MATLAB.

Take the following example:

```
x = linspace(0, 2*pi);  % Sample data.

for i = 1:3                             % Loop 3 times.
   h = figure;                          % Create figure window and capture its handle.
   plot(i*sin(x));                      % Plot some data.
   saveas(h, sprintf('fig%d.fig', i));  % Save figure to .fig file format.
   close(h);                            % Delete the figure.
end
```

Now you can tell MATLAB to open one of the figures using the [`openfig`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/openfig.html) function. For example, let's open the second figure `fig2.fig`. Go to the Command Window and type `openfig('fig2')` (including the `.fig` extension in the file name is optional).

```
>> openfig('fig2')

ans = 

  Figure (1) with properties:

      Number: 1
        Name: ''
       Color: [0.9400 0.9400 0.9400]
    Position: [520 371 560 420]
       Units: 'pixels'

  Show all properties
```

[image: the second figure]

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your time and excellent answer. This is really simple and easy to handle solution. Thanks a lot. Means a lot to me.

Comment: Glad to help! Make sure to explore [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47656107/3599179), specially if you want to create a dialog box. Cheers! :)

Comment: yes for sure i have mixed both stuffs together as nice explanation is available in answer below .Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is the following:
1) You save the figures as `.fig` in a dedicated folder using the `saveas` command, e.g.:

```
saveas(gcf,['FileName_',num2str(idx),'.fig']);
```

where `idx` is the index associated with the figure number (so in 75 in the example you mentioned). For simplicity, I would save all of them in one folder.

2) You use `inputdlg` to create an input dialog box, where you type in the index you want. Then, you run `uiopen(['FileName_',idxFromInput,'.fig'])`, which will display the figure. Note that the output from `inputdlg` is normally a string, so you don't need `num2str` here.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer . I have voted up for you but I have selected upper answer as it worked easily for me.

Comment: your answer is great for curiosity i tried this and its working great just one issue i am having can you just provide me feedback about it if possible

Comment: `x = linspace(0, 2*pi);  % Sample data.
basePath = 'surface_plot/offset%d.fig'
offset = [2.5:4.5];
for i = 1:numel(offset)                             % Loop 3 times.
   h(i) = figure(i);                          % Create figure window and capture its handle.
   plot(i*sin(x));                      % Plot some data.
   saveas(gcf,[ 'surface_plot/offset',num2str(offset(i)),'.fig']);
   close(h(i));                            % Delete the figure.
end
x = inputdlg ;
uiopen(['surface_plot/', offsetx ,'.fig'])`

Comment: `uiopen(['surface_plot/', offsetx ,'.fig'])` this command i am having issue as output of inputdlg is string so i am having error here i tried to use str2num but not working if i put offset3.5 value with which i have saved my figure then this command works fine  like this but it will make it manual `uiopen(['surface_plot/', 'offset3.5' ,'.fig'])`

Comment: If I see this correctly, then your problem is in `uiopen([`surface_plot/',offsetx,'.fig'])`. The issue is that you are referring to a variable `offsetx` which does not exist. Rather, you should write: `uiopen(['surface_plot/offset',x,'.fig'])`, which should work. However, sometimes the output from `inputdlg` is a cell, so you need to use `data = str2num(x{:})` instead. Just try to see what errors MATLAB gives you.

Comment: great  `data = str2num(x{:})` this worked perfectly Thanks a lot for your time and great answer . Have a nice time.